# Changing zoom state in d3js bilevel partition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to link a bilevel partition (based on mbostock's example - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371) to a HTML select menu, so that clicking through the svg changes the select menu, and selecting a menu option changes the svg.

Here's my current attempt: http://bl.ocks.org/tomalrussell/2c8c5e24bf614f80e3bc

This re-renders the whole chart when the select menu changes, which mixes up the colours and doesn't transition in the same way as when clicking on the svg.

Can I trigger the zoom function on the select menu change event? Or is there another approach to getting the same behaviour?